# How do I access Initiation Form data inside my SharePoint 2013 workflow

Tags: workflow, initiation-form, sharepoint-on-prem

I am working in SharePoint 2013 SP1 on Windows Server 2012.
I have a VS.NET 2013 solution that has a Workflow project and a custom Assn and Init. forms.
I have been able to send Assn data to the workflow using the below code

```
  //PeopleEditor HMgr
            var strPPHMgrValue = new Object();
            var html = $("#ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_PeopleEditorHMgr_upLevelDiv");
            strPPHMgrValue["GroupName"] = $("#divEntityData", html).attr("key");                
            metadata['HMgrGroup'] = strPPHMgrValue["GroupName"];
```

Then in my workflow I use the GetConfiguationValue Task to set it.

When I created my new Initiation form, I see where the values are called "wfParams".  and the GetConfiguationValue doesn't work.

So how do I send my Init form values to the workflow?